# try catch isnt working as expected, with fluentmigrator

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

We are using fluentmigrator and sql server 2017. Below piece of code throws exception but catch block is not catching.

This throws exception because the command ADD SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION is not available in sql server 2017, it was introduced in 2019.

Execute is of type : IExecuteExpressionRoot

```
        public void AddSensitivityClassificationSql(string schema, string table, string column, string label, string informationType, string rank)
        {
            try
            {
                Execute.Sql($@"ADD SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION TO [{schema}].[{table}].[{column}] WITH (LABEL = '{label}', INFORMATION_TYPE = '{informationType}', RANK = {rank})");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Because of this, program crashes. Can someone help me understand how i can catch this exception?

stack trace:

The error was Incorrect syntax near 'SENSITIVITY'.

---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 'SENSITIVITY'.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at FluentMigrator.Runner.Processors.SqlServer.SqlServerProcessor.ExecuteNonQuery(String sql) ClientConnectionId:83abb1dc-5b23-4065-af3e-52e6f95e09d0 Error Number:102,State:1,Class:15 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at FluentMigrator.Runner.Processors.SqlServer.SqlServerProcessor.ExecuteNonQuery(String sql) at FluentMigrator.Runner.Processors.SqlServer.SqlServerProcessor.Process(String sql) at FluentMigrator.Runner.Processors.SqlServer.SqlServerProcessor.Execute(String template, Object[] args) at FluentMigrator.Runner.Processors.ProcessorBase.Execute(String sql) at FluentMigrator.Expressions.ExecuteSqlStatementExpression.ExecuteWith(IMigrationProcessor processor) at FluentMigrator.Runner.MigrationRunner.<>c__DisplayClass80_0.<ExecuteExpressions>b__1() at FluentMigrator.Runner.StopWatch.Time(Action action) at FluentMigrator.Runner.MigrationRunner.ExecuteExpressions(ICollection`1 expressions)
at FluentMigrator.Runner.MigrationRunner.ExecuteMigration(IMigration migration, Action`2 getExpressions)
at FluentMigrator.Runner.MigrationRunner.ApplyMigrationUp(IMigrationInfo migrationInfo, Boolean useTransaction)
at FluentMigrator.Runner.MigrationRunner.MigrateUp(Int64 targetVersion, Boolean useAutomaticTransactionManagement)
at FluentMigrator.Runner.MigrationRunner.MigrateUp(Boolean useAutomaticTransactionManagement)
at FluentMigrator.Runner.MigrationRunner.MigrateUp()

Comment: Would be good to include full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: This piece of code is not able to catch exception, and program just crashes without a trace. How can i get stack trace in this scenario?

Comment: If on windows then it should produce event log for example.

Comment: Crashes without a trace? Sounds like you are invoking `async` methods somewhere from one/some of your own methods that are not declared with `async` themselves.

Comment: @Evk added stack trace

Comment: Seems AddSensitivityClassificationSql is not present in that stack trace.

Comment: Not familiar with the library but it looks like methods such as these *define* the code to be executed but it's a separate step for the code to be *applied* to the database, and it's only during application that the exception is thrown.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, that is exactly what is happening. I'm just wondering if this framework support immediate execution.

Comment: This probably should be asked here: https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator/issues